# Build fails when build parameters contain `-gcflags"all=-N -l"` and import net/http In MacOS

Tags: macos, go, x509

When I try debug, `go build` parameters contains `-gcflags "all=-N -l"`, and I import `net/http`, then build will be fail.

I tried reinstalling golang using brew, not work.

and tried using the [offical installation](https://golang.org/dl/) after uninstalling, not work.

And I'm try `sudo mv /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools CommandLineTools.old && xcode-select --install`, not work.

At JimB's suggestion, I tried `go env -w CGO_ENABLED=0`, so that I can build correctly.

Any suggestions?

build fail message:

```
# crypto/x509
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/src/crypto/x509/root_cgo_darwin.go:17:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:31:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecItem.h:452:49: error: expected ','
    API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(NA), bridgeos(NA));
                                                ^
    ......
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/libexec/src/crypto/x509/root_cgo_darwin.go:17:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/Security.h:35:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecImportExport.h:317:55: error: expected ','
          API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(NA), bridgeos(NA));
                                                      ^
    ......
/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecImportExport.h:656:49: error: expected ','
    API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.7), ios(NA), bridgeos(NA));
                                                ^
    ......

27 errors generated.
```

```golang
package main
import "os"
func main() {
    println(os.Args)
}
> go build main.go                       # success
> go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" main.go  # success

--------------------------------------

package main
import "net/http"
func main() {
    println(http.DefaultClient)
}
> go build main.go                       # success
> go build -gcflags "all=-N -l" main.go  # fail       <-----------
```

> MacOS version: 10.13.6
>
> Xcode version: 10.0
>
> Go version 1.14

```sh
> go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/XXX/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/XXX/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build994818786=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I find some like question: [Go: build error when compiling unit tests (I'm trying to mock influxdb types)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498765/go-build-error-when-compiling-unit-tests-im-trying-to-mock-influxdb-types)

But I did not use relative imports

Comment: Try installing the official Go version according to the official installation instructions (instead of brew).

Comment: @Volker I tried it and it still does n’t work

Comment: Do you require CGO for anything specific to your application? Can you build your test binary with `CGO_ENABLED=false`?

Comment: @JimB It works! I execute `go env -w CGO_ENABLED=0`, then build will success.
So the reason for the error may be xcode? I will try to reinstall xcode later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `go env -w CGO_ENABLED=0` can solve this problem temporarily.
2. This problem has not happened again after upgrading MacOS and XCode.

now my versions:

> MacOS 10.15.3
>
> XCode 11.3.1(11C504)